# jQuery Slider define increments/steps?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jquery slider I where I would like to define the step (increments). Currently, as it stands it goes up by 1 and I'd like to change this to 100 or 1000.

Here is my code so far:

```js
$('body').on('click', '#modern-filter-listing .stm-clear-listing-one-unit', function(){
  var selectToClear = $(this).data('select');
  if(typeof selectToClear != 'undefined') {
    if (selectToClear != 'price' && $('select[name=' + selectToClear + ']').length > 0) {
      $('select[name=' + selectToClear + ']').val('').change();
  } else {
      var $priceRange = $('#stm-price-range');
      if ($priceRange.length > 0) {
        $priceRange.slider('values', [stmOptions.min, stmOptions.max]);
        $("#stm_filter_min_price").val(stmOptions.min);
        $("#stm_filter_max_price").val(stmOptions.max);
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Here is my php html that executes the slider:

[Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/svtUjhtU)

Any help would be great.

Comment: please share you `HTML` code.

Comment: Just added the html/php